# install RStudio-server in Centos Gateway node of cloudera 6.0

Tags: r, centos7, cloudera, rstudio-server

I am not sure about where I can write this question but I need try all paths. I have a development cluster of Cloudera with:

- 1 master.
- 3 workers.
- 1 gateway node.

I am working in a Data Science group and they need a RStudio Server for working, additionally this RStudio-server should be able to connect with kerberos to my cloudera cluster.

My planning for resolve it is to install the RStudio-server in the gateway node, I don't know if this point can be my mistake but I put here ever steps I do in this node:

1. Stop cloudera agent: `sudo service cloudera-scm-agent stop`
2. Update OS :

   ```
   sudo yum install epel-release;
   sudo yum update;
   sudo shutdown -r now;
   ```
3. install R from yum : `sudo yum install R`
4. get Rstudio server:

   ```
   wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.463-x86_64.rpm
   sudo yum install rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.463-x86_64.rpm
   ```

And from here all my problems:

1. When you install RStudio-server your user and password of Linux will be the
   default user in RStudio-server, but in my case when I go to IP:8787 and I
   login with my user and password I receive always incorrect login.

Solution: I copy the content of /etc/pam.d/login in /etc/pam.d/rstudio

2. After before step I got he login but he RStudio-server tell all time the
   server can not connect with the service, I don't understand the
   description but I watch the logs and I see things like it:

   > ERROR system error 1 (Operation not permitted) [path=/tmp/rstudio-rsession/user-d]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::remove() const /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:692; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1743
3. I suppose it could be some problems with permissions but If I change
   permission suddenly I can not access to my node, because the
   permission in the home/user about files like .ssh o .bashrc or
   bash_profile have changed.

I don't know what Can I do? It can not be so much difficult, any help will be fine for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you change the permissions in step 3? BTW, https://community.rstudio.com/ might be a better venue for questions about RStudio Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED - I did everything again, and the main problem was that I was in an azure node with centos, and this command:

```
sudo yum install epel-release;
```

Gave me updates the next day to this problem. These were the steps for installing, from home of your machine:

```
$ sudo su
$ service cloudera-scm-agent stop
$ yum erase R*
$ yum install epel-release
$ yum update
$ reboot
$ sudo su
$ service cloudera-scm-agent stop
$ yum install R -y
$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.463-x86_64.rpm
$ yum install rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.463-x86_64.rpm
$ reboot machine
$ sudo su
$ yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
$ R
$ install.packages('txtplot')
$ yum install libxml2-devel
$ yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
```